# Is there a minimum amount of resources per seed?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm playing Minecraft on the Xbox, and I realized I almost have all the achievements, so I'm looking to complete the ones I still have left to do.

One of which is the baking a cake achievement.  I have the three buckets of milk, and more than enough wheat, and an egg. The problem is the sugar.  I have found sugar cane, and made it into paper to create another map (I lost the first one).  However, after searching half the world, that was the only sugar cane group I have ever found.

**Is there a minimum amount of each resource spawned per seed?
I know the map is random, but are there always at least x diamond ore, y gold ore, z pumpkins, etc.?**

Is there more sugar cane to be found on the half of the map I have not yet explored? Or am I most likely wasting my time?

PS- most of my map (so far) is a snow biome, with some forest(?) biome around it

Comment: I know the question has been answered but dont you still have some from the first bit you found? For me a general of minecraft is to destroy the first you find and plant it when you build a farm. Just a little tip for the future.

Comment: @AidanMueller I'm new to minecraft, I know better now, but at the time I turned all my sugar cane into paper :/ but yep, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yes, the nice thing about sugar cane is that although it is pretty rare to find, it grows super fast and if you make a small farm, soon you will be swimming in it.

Comment: Also, here is an interesting video on how many of some various resources are in an XBox Minecraft world: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7uLLuvRDb0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no minimum resource level per map.  The entire map is generated procedurally with no consideration for previously generated pieces.

If you are looking for [sugar cane](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sugar_Cane), your best bet is to find a large body of water and walk around the edge, as it will only grow adjacent to water.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! The link also gives me tips on how to farm, so if I do find any more (finger crossed) I'll be able to duplicated them. Thanks again!

Comment: The good thing about all of these things (Sugarcane, wheat, etc) is once you find one you pretty much have an infinite supply.